# can i set the pivot of one object as that of another one?

Tags: axis

I have a clock and a dial, and i want to set the pivot point of the dial as that of the clock, so i could rotate the dial freely and its center would stay at the same place. how can i do such a thing? right now the pivot point of the dial is a bit off ever so slightly and i want it exactly in the center. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Select the clock object in object mode.  Shift s (snap) -> snap cursor to selection.  Select the dial in object mode.  Shift ctrl alt c (set origin) -> set origin to cursor.  Done.

Comment: Thank you so much!